# Unable to output file in a Pester test

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

I have a script extracting records from log files to a text file. It works fine in the PS command line. In Pester, it seems that the output file was not created. I use Add-content to create the file inside the script.

I'm new to Pester. How should I test the output file generated by a script?

The test doExport-logRecords2.Test.ps1:

```
# creating test data
$workDir = (Get-Item .).FullName
# create source logs dir
mkdir $workDir\logs -Force
# check-Result_20200702a.log 5 lines with exact 2 records all after 2020-06-01
Remove-Item $workDir\logs\check-Result_20200702a.log -force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
add-content $workDir\logs\check-Result_20200702a.log "2020-07-02T15:37:25.6644206+08:00 Nulla amet do Lorem eiusmod nulla culpa officia nisi consectetur."
add-content $workDir\logs\check-Result_20200702a.log "2020-07-02T15:37:26.0648662+08:00 Sint enim irure Lorem ea ipsum irure et elit esse consequat ut velit do."
add-content $workDir\logs\check-Result_20200702a.log "2020-07-02T15:37:44.5430983+08:00 Tempor consequat amet excepteur veniam laboris occaecat sunt esse et officia nisi."
add-content $workDir\logs\check-Result_20200702a.log "2020-07-02T15:37:44.6415035+08:00 Abnormality Found:"
add-content $workDir\logs\check-Result_20200702a.log "2020-07-02T15:37:52.4064969+08:00 Operator acknowledged the above alert."
Describe 'basic set 1' {
    It '1 log file with 2 records' {
        Remove-Item "$workDir\output.log" -force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        & $workDir\doExport-logRecords -to "$workDir\output.log" -from "$workDir\logs\" -logFileNamePattern "check-Result_20200702a.log" -since "2020-06-01"
        start-sleep -Seconds 3
        [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'; (get-content "$workDir\output.log" | Measure-Object -line).lines | should -be 3
        (Select-String "2 record\(s\) found" "$workDir\output.log").Matches[0].Success | should -be $true
    }
}
```

The test result:

```
PS D:\users\chingNotCHing\bin> Invoke-Pester .\doExport-logRecords2.Test.ps1

Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery finished in 24ms.
get-content : Cannot find path 'D:\users\chingNotCHing\bin\output.log' 
because it does not exist.
At D:\users\chingNotCHing\bin\doExport-logRecords2.Test.ps1:17 char:72
+ ... urrentUICulture = 'en-US'; (get-content "$workDir\output.log" | Measu ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\users\chingN...\bin\output.log:String) [ 
   Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
 
[-] basic set 1.1 log file with 2 records 3.03s (3.03s|1ms)
 Expected 3, but got 0.
 at [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'; (get-content "$workDir\out
put.log" | Measure-Object -line).lines | should -be 3, D:\users\chingNotCHingk\bin\doExport-logRecords2.Test.ps1:17
 at <ScriptBlock>, D:\users\chingNotCHing\bin\doExport-logRecords2.Test.p
s1:17
Tests completed in 3.14s
Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Pester: 5.0.2

PS: 5.1

Comment: Its unfortunately not possible to troubleshoot this without knowing what your `doExport-logRecords` function does. If you edit your question to include it we might be able to help further.

Comment: As an aside your use of `$workDir` could be replaced by the automatic variable `$pwd` (present working directory).

Comment: @MarkWragg Is it a proper Pester way to test the output file content?

Comment: Yeah there’s nothing wrong with what you’re doing in theory. You might want to look at using the TestDrive: feature of pester for writing your files to. That would save you doing manual clean ups and avoid risking deleting real files.